# Why does dataTable.Select always returning empty result?

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
var tmpTable = dt.Select("strText IN('" + strZipList + "')");
if (tmpTable.Any())
{
dt = tmpTable.CopyToDataTable();
}
```

dt = DataTable and
strText is of type `string`
strZipList = string('1','2',....etc)

**Edited:**
DataTable structure created as:

```
private DataTable CreateListTabel()
{
    DataTable _dtList = new DataTable();
    DataColumn dc1 = new DataColumn("strText", typeof(String));
    DataColumn dc2 = new DataColumn("strValue", typeof(String));
    DataColumn dc3 = new DataColumn("isSelected", typeof(Boolean));
    DataColumn dc5 = new DataColumn("intSrNo", typeof(Int32));
    DataColumn dc6 = new DataColumn("intID", typeof(Int32));
    DataColumn dc7 = new DataColumn("isExcluded", typeof(Boolean));
    DataColumn dc8 = new DataColumn("isDisabled", typeof(Boolean));
    _dtList.Columns.Add(dc1);
    _dtList.Columns.Add(dc2);
    _dtList.Columns.Add(dc3);
    _dtList.Columns.Add(dc5);
    _dtList.Columns.Add(dc6);
    _dtList.Columns.Add(dc7);
    _dtList.Columns.Add(dc8);
    _dtList.AcceptChanges();
    return _dtList;
}
```

Where does it going wrong?

Comment: we would need more information on what data you have

Comment: strText must be inferred as variable I suppose , but it is used as a string. Just an observation from the first look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you be more specific in the `strZipList` string format?

> strZipList = string('1,','2',....etc)

It should be like `'1, 2, 3 ...'`, not like `'1', '2', '3'...`

**OOPS!**
I mean: 
It should be like `'1', '2', '3' ...'`, not like `'1,','2'`!

By the way, be sure to check your strings are EXACTLY the same when comaring them (no extra spaces, etc..).
`'1'` is not the same as `' 1'` (look at extra spaces...)

Comment: that's typos, I've checked that is ok..!

Comment: Could you submit an example of  the content of both strZipList and strText?

Comment: **OOPS!**, strZipList was not in proper format. It was `'1,2,3,4,5'`. Thanks @AdamCalvetBohl.

Answer (score 1):

Lets say that your search list is `List<string>`. In that case, you could search like in this example (sorry, I wrote an example before you explained your table structure).

also, you can search it using LINQ, as shown in another line
In case you're selecting using `string` variable, look at third line.
Hope this helps

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("column", typeof(string));

table.Rows.Add("1");
table.Rows.Add("2");
table.Rows.Add("2");
table.Rows.Add("3");
table.Rows.Add("4");
table.Rows.Add("4");

List<string> searchList = new List<string> { "1", "2" };
string searchString = "1, 2";

//DataTable.Select(string) example
var filteredTable = table.Select("column in ("  + string.Join(", ", searchList.ToArray()) + ")");
//LINQ
var filteredTable2 = table.AsEnumerable().Where(row => searchList.Contains(row.Field<string>("column"))).CopyToDataTable();
//using string for search
var filteredTable3 = table.Select("column in (" + searchString + ")");
```